# Why is the heating unit not on top?

Tags: heated-bed, printer-building

Most printers are build the following (please excuse if I do not use the correct terms)

A heating unit mounted below an aluminum build plate and then some surface on top that can be printed on like glas or some fancy material.

Why is the heating unit not sandwiched above the aluminum bed and the the surface that can be printed on?

wouldn't it be more efficient having the heating unit closer to the printed part and more "insulation" on the bottom?

Comment: You're asking about the bed heating right?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: You can add insulation under the bed heater, assuming there is sufficient space.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of the following reasons why heating units in 3D printers are typically below the build plate such as:

- Uniform Heat Distribution: An aluminum build plate evenly distributes heat across the printing surface.
- Safety and Insulation: This setup provides insulation, reducing the risk of burns and maintaining a stable temperature environment.

The stable temperature also would allow for a more gradual cooling of printed layers, potentially minimizing warping issues.

Placing the heating unit on top might perhaps improve heat transfer efficiency but would likely lead to overheating, uneven temperature control, safety issues, or print quality issues.